# React-redux-router push with action/reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

Ive got a simple click handler which passes an object (selectedPost) to an action - below is the component:

```
class SearchBarContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="center-xs">
            <p>To get started, type in some keywords below</p>
          </div>
          <SearchBar onTermChange={this.props.actions.loadPosts} onNull={this.props.actions.nullPosts}/>  
          <PostList posts={this.props.posts} isFetching={this.props.isFetching} onClick={this.props.actions.selectPost}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the action:

```
export function selectPost(post) {
  return {
    type: SELECT_POST,
    payload: post
  }
}
```

What I want to do is at the same time change the url with push to /product/foo but I cant quite figure out where I put this code - any help appreciated

Comment: define a fun inside class and assign to onClick, inside that fun first call the action then change the route.

Comment: Ah yes thank you that makes sense, could you maybe send some sample code im still struggling

Comment: check @shubham's answer it will solve your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by calling a function `onClick` and then changing the route as well as calling the action from within the function

```
class SearchBarContainer extends Component {
  selectPost = (post) => {
      this.props.history.push('/product/foo');
      this.props.actions.selectPost(post)
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="center-xs">
            <p>To get started, type in some keywords below</p>
          </div>
          <SearchBar onTermChange={this.props.actions.loadPosts} onNull={this.props.actions.nullPosts}/>  
          <PostList posts={this.props.posts} isFetching={this.props.isFetching} onClick={this.selectPost}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(SearchBarContainer);
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much. The only extra thing I needed to do was to add the post object into the selectPost method:   selectPost = (post) => {
    this.props.history.push('/product/foo');
    this.props.actions.selectPost(post);
  }

Comment: I love this approach because I am just passing data from redux into the next component so the loading is instant and also I dont even need url parameters for a network request - hence /product/foo